# (awk) writing content between pattern 1 and second occurrence of pattern 2 into separate files

Tags: linux, bash, awk

```
errors=$(mktemp -d) || exit 1

cat "$logFile" | awk -v d=$errors '/ ERROR /, /********************************************************************************/ {if ($0 ~ / ERROR /) {n++} ; print > d "/" n}'
```

This writes lines between ERROR and first occurrence of ******************************************************************************** into separate files, but I need write until second occurrence of ******************************************************************************** happens. How can this be done with awk?

Simplified example of input $logFile

```
2021-02-04T07:26:31,246+0000    ERROR 
********************************************************************************
CONTENT
********************************************************************************

2021-02-04T07:26:31,248+0000    ERROR 
********************************************************************************
CONTENT
********************************************************************************
```

The desired output would be

file 1

```
2021-02-04T07:26:31,246+0000    ERROR 
********************************************************************************
CONTENT
********************************************************************************
```

file 2

```
2021-02-04T07:26:31,248+0000    ERROR 
********************************************************************************
CONTENT
********************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
errors=$(mktemp -d) || exit 1

cat "$logFile" | awk -v d=$errors '/ ERROR /, /\*\*\*\*/ && i++ {if ($0 ~ / ERROR /) {j++}; if (i <= 2) print > d "/" j; if (i == 2) i = 0}'
```

Explanation

Pipe content of $logFile to awk

```
cat "$logFile" | awk
```

Set awk variable d as temp folder

```
-v d=$errors
```

First pattern to match

```
'/ ERROR /,
```

Second pattern to match and increase counter i when matches (guess * has to be escaped since its's a wildcard, won't bother to escape all of them)

```
/\*\*\*\*/ && i++
```

Not really sure what this does but it should increase counter j for each ERROR line

```
{if ($0 ~ / ERROR /) {j++};
```

Now if i counter is less or equal to 2 we print the line into d folder with j as file name

```
if (i <= 2) print > d "/" j;
```

Finally when second /****/ happens i should be 2 so we reset it to 0

```
if (i == 2) i = 0}'
```